# Connect docker container to remote MYSQL database with bridge driver

Tags: docker

I'm wondering about this scenario:

1. Dockerhost with IP address `192.168.1.10`
2. Container with php application inside the dockerhost, driver bridge
   with IP `172.18.0.3`
3. Mysql cluster server with IP address `192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12, 192.168.1.13`

The connection from the server `192.168.1.10` to the Mysql server `192.168.1.11` is success, docker container (`172.18.0.0`) can't reach the network (`192.168.1.0`).

Obviusly with network mode host or macvlan the host will allow to reach the mysql, but i don't want bind al local ports to the container, because multiple containers will coexist, and i don't want use multiple IP's for each container, because the incoming traffic will be routed by an ELB.

The question is quite simple, using bridge driver, how can i connect to mysql private host.

Comment: Could you try to enter in the container and do a traceroute to 192.168.1.11? To enter in the container you can use this command: docker exec -ti [container-name] bash

Comment: You bringme the light, it seems something wrong with the image. tested on apine and wordpress an can arrive by default to the container. I'm using this image docker pull bitnami/moodle can arrive to the remote mysql but cannot populate the database, the error must be other thing. This can be closed. Thanks you.